# align items in a form at center

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to the front end . I actually want to make a markup which looks like ,

[image]

so, I tried in the following way,

```
 <div className="row">
    <div className="col-xs-4">
      <div className="has-feedback">
        <label className="control-label">Search Job</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputValidation" placeholder="Search"/>
               <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Now, Here, 
  What I am getting is

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: it's bootstrap, right? if yes simply read this : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline or this : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#inline-forms

Comment: Add: has-feedback { display: flex; } to your CSS

Comment: @Gerard it's a react code, so className is correct

Comment: @TemaniAfif Cheers. Comment modified

Comment: Assuming you're using bootstrap, you can use `form-inline` class on your form.

Comment: layout issue, the container has not enough space to accommodate both label and input as both of the element is an inline element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete code for you :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<style>
  .mi-abc {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightgrey;
  }
  .mi-control {
    width: 75%;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .mi-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 20px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>        
  <div class="col-md-3 mi-abc">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <label class="mi-label">Search Job</label>
      <input type="text" class="mi-control" placeholder="Search"/>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search mi-icon"></span>
    </div>
  </div>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use float property.

```
.control-label,.form-control{
        float:left;
    }
```

it will put elements from left for you. so label comes first and then input will come at the right of it

also you can use flex

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="staticEmail2" class="sr-only">Search</label>
    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="staticEmail2" value="" placeholder="search">
  </div>
  </div>
```

[Bootstrap Form page](http://%20https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use "class" instead of "className", you can either use the "pull-left" class which is already available in bootstrap documentation.
you can use the below link as a reference.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the best way would be with the flex property on `.has-feedback` as follows:

```
.has-feedback{
  display: flex;
}
```

By default this will align it's children horizontally.

You could also `float` the children of `.has-feedback` left and right.

If you choose to float the children however, be prepared to have to clear `.has-feedback` so that it can calculate the height around it's children. You can find an example on how to do that here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/